# Unix Recursively delete files and folders

Tags: bash, unix, recursion

So I am working on a program that delete files and folders recursively. For some reason I am stucked in endless loop. Please point out where I am wrong.

```
for file in $1
       do
               if [ -f $file ] #If it is a file just delete it
               then
                       echo "delete $file"

               elif [ -d $file ] #if it is a folder
               then
                        #look inside and see if it is empty or not
                       if [ "$(ls -A $file)" ] 

                       then
                                recursive $file #recursively call 
                       else
                                #if the folder is empty just delete it
                               echo "delete $file"
                       fi
               fi

       done
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use `rm -rf /path/to/folder`? The details of what -rf does can be found with `rm --help`.

Comment: Not sure, but I think you might need to `cd` into the next folder before you make the recursive call.

Comment: And exclude `..` from the loop or you will run into serious trouble running it recursively.

Comment: @Prix: I think using `for file in $1` will not include hidden files (like `.` and `..`) by default, right?

Comment: @justhalf I guess it depends on how the argument is for example `/*` may grab those. But I would still prefer to use `rm` instead of reinventing the wheel unless there is a reason not to or that you would need to make your own function.

Comment: @Prix: Hmm, `/*` doesn't grab hidden files, although `.*` does. I agree that we should use `rm` if we _just_ want to delete the files. Dunno what other requirements the OP has in mind.

Comment: @justhalf well you can use `-rf` to recursively delete an entire folder so unless he gives us more information...

Comment: The requirement is that I am building a function that deletes all the files and folders recursively. Lets call the script my_rm. When I type in my_rm -r filename, the script will recursively delete files and then recurse down the subfolders in the directory called "bin". I know I can just use built in command but there is no fun in it.

Comment: I am new to UNIX scripting too. Learned it like a week ago....

Answer (score 3):

You have

```
for file in $1
```

...

```
recursive $file #recursively call
```

This effectively turns into repeating

```
for file in $file
```

That is, it keeps repeating for same first dir entry. You need to think the whole function again, either pass different parameter in recursive call, or do not use `for` over `$1`. Simplest may be to change the `for` (untested):

```
for file in "$1/*" "$1/.*"
```

Also add test for case where `$file` is `.` or `..`, or remove `$file/.*` part from my `for`.

---

About debugging bash scripts, following two `set` options are often useful, you can for example add them to start of your script.

```
set -x # print every final command line when it is executed
set +x # turn -x off

set -v # print script lines as they are read
set +v # turn -v off
```

For more about this, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951336/how-to-debug-a-bash-script).

Comment: I used for file in $(tree -ifa -L 1 $1 --noreport | sort -r) and still get in infinite unless I actually delete the files instead of echoing out. Is there like a better way to rewrite it? I am pretty much out of idea for now

Comment: @WaiHein Well, hard for me to debug without actually writing a script and running it, but see the edit about doing the debugging yourself. But most likely the first item in `for` is the directory itself... to avoid that, you use tail to filter out first line, untested example: `$(tree -ifa -L 1 $1 --noreport | tail -n+2 | sort -r)`

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you're trying to achieve, I suspect you'd be better off using the `find` command instead of rolling your own shell script.

For example, the following command should delete "just files" named `foo.txt` recursively starting at the current directory, and show you the list of files being deleted.

```
find . -name foo.txt -type f -exec rm -v {} \;
```

You can `man find` for details on how to use this tool, but basically the options are along the lines of:

> find *path* [*path* ...] [*expression*]

where *path* is one or more start directories for your recursive search, and *expression* is a list of conditions or actions to perform.

In the example above, we have two obvious conditions -- `-name foo.txt` denotes the filename, and *-type f* says "this is a normal file".  The third option in the expression executes a command line terminated with an escaped semicolon, replacing `{}` with the name of each file found.

Also, when processing multiple filenames, beware not to parse the output of `ls`.  For details read [ParsingLs from Greg's wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Lastly, if you're trying to create a script that will take multiple filenames to delete, you could go with something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

for file in $@; do
  find . -type f -name "$file" -exec rm -v {} \;
done
```

Note that this will also work in simpler POSIX style shells, it doesn't require bash.

Comment: I am coding a script that works like rm -ri. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

So I kinda rewrote it. The code is not that efficient but it does the work.

```
recursive()
{
        # create a file
        touch $HOME/temp_file #create a file
        tree -fi $1 > $HOME/temp_file #tree it up and pump it in the file

        touch $HOME/temp_file
        tree -fid $1 > $HOME/temp_file #tree it up and pump it in the file

        count=$(wc -l $HOME/temp_file | cut -d " " -f1)

        #loop thru the file that contains only directory 
        for ((i=1;i<=$[$count-2];i++))
        do
               args=$(sed -n $i"p" $HOME/temp_file) #grab line by line
               if [ -d $args ] #if it is a folder
                then
                        if recurse_down $args # if recurse down interactive flag is set
                        then
                                if  [ "$(ls -A $args)" ] #if dir is not empty
                                then
                                        touch $HOME/temp_file2
                                #store only file name in another file this time
                                ls $args | grep -v ^d > $HOME/temp_file2

                                        count2=$(wc -l $HOME/temp_file2 |  cut -d " " -f1)
                                        for ((z=1;z<=$count2;z++))
                                        do
                                                file=$(sed -n $z"p" $HOME/temp_file2)
                                                echo "deleting  $file"

                                                #call delete function and pass in filename
                                                # and the path of it
                                                delete $file $args  
                                        done
                                else
                                        echo "Empty dir. Just delete it"
                                        delete $args
                                fi
                         else
                                exit
                        fi

                fi



         done


}

delete()
{
        # $2 for path and $1 for filename
        echo "1 is $1"
        echo "2 is $2"
        File=$2/$1
        echo "Fileeeeeeee is $File"
        #echo "node is $node"

        node=$(stat -c%i $File) #get inode number of the file
        opFile="$recycleBin"/$(basename "$File")"_$node" #append it
        echo "opFile is $opFile"
        no_basename=$(basename "$File") #get basename

        # it will be like f8_1287540:/home/waiyan.hein/bin/d9/d1/f8
        echo "${no_basename}_$node:`pwd`/$File" >> $HOME/.restore.info

        #now move the file into destination folder
        mv $File $opFile


}
```

Comment: Maybe there is a more efficient way to write replacement script for "rm -ri name" commmand